# Key/value pairs are not allowed within a setPylance

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

> [how to solve, please(since i had problems with concate function)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fVpvw.jpg)

Comment: Please post your actual code, not an image. Is the title also the error message you're getting?

Comment: Please edit your question so that its body contains the full error traceback.